# Delphi - Change TextRenderingDefault

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

My text in FireMonkey isn't as sharp as the rest of windows text.

I read this website: http://i-logic.com/firemonkey/fuzzy.htm

Now i am wondering how to change the text rendering to `TextRenderingHintClearTypeGridFit` or `TextRenderingHintSystemDefault`. This is recommended by the author at the end of the page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of Delphi? The text rendering constants you mention are part of GDI+, which on new FMX versions is a very last-stage fallback.

Comment: I am the author of that page. The info was made for XE2 and is probably obsolete. But you can search search for TextRenderingHintClearTypeGridFit in the FMX.Canvas.GDIP.pas source file and you will see it.